# Need help with inequality to understand stability analysis

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, partial-differential-equations, finite-difference-methods

I have this

$$ | \xi |^{2} = 1 - 4p^{2}(1-p^{2})s^{4}$$

where $s = \sin\left(\frac\omega 2 \right)$. The method is said to be stable if $ | \xi|\leq1$.

From here I am supposed to deduce that this scheme is stable for $ -1 \leq p \leq 1$, but I do not know where to go from here... Can anyone suggest how?

Comment: What is the premise and what is the conclusion precisely?

Comment: VON Neumann stability analysis, what do you mean by given~?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2743887/lax-wendroff-method-for-linear-advection-stability-analysis/2744346?noredirect=1#comment5678143_2744346 this is the full question and I am stuck at this point

Answer (score 1):

**Hints:**

1. If $p^2\in[0,1]$ then $4p^2(1-p^2)\in [0, 1]$, say by AM-GM.
2. If $p^2>1$, then $(1-p^2)$ is negative, so your LHS is $>1$ unless $s=0$.

Comment: Can you explain the first first line of your comment? What is AmM GM??

Comment: AM-GM refers to the inequality between Arithmetic Mean and Geometric Mean. If that’s not familiar, note $(x+y)^2=(x-y)^2+4xy\geqslant 4xy$. Now set $x=p^2$ and $y=1-p^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a correct analysis?

$ 1-4p^{2}(1-p^{2}) s^{4} \leq 1 $

$ -4p^{2}(1-p^{2}) s^{4} \leq 0 $

$ p^{2}(1-p^{2}) \geq 0$ Since sine is bounded between 0 and 1

$p^{2}  \geq 0 $ is always true. So $ 1-p^{2} \geq 0 $ gives $p^{2} \leq 1 $

Comment: Yes, it is fine. To be completely exhaustive, one should distinguish the case $s=0$ from $s\neq 0$ when dividing by $s^4$.

Comment: Thank you, also since this equals $ \xi^{2} $ do i have to also look at $ \xi_{\pm}$?

Comment: Proving $|\xi|^2 \leq 1$ is fine since equivalent to $|\xi| \leq 1$.