# Numerical schemes for linear advection: stability, dissipation, dispersion

Tags: partial-differential-equations, numerical-methods, hyperbolic-equations

> A generalized numerical scheme for the linear hyperbolic equation $u_t + au_x = 0$ has the following form
>   $$
> \frac{u_j^{n+1} - u_j^n}{\Delta t} + a\frac{u_{j+1}^{n} - u_{j-1}^n}{2\Delta x} - \chi \frac{u_{j+1}^{n} - 2u_{j}^n + u_{j-1}^n}{\Delta x^2} = 0 .
> $$
>   a) Find the values of $\chi$ so that the above scheme is the central-explicit, forward, backward, Lax-Friedrich and Lax-Wendroff scheme.
>
> b) What is the order of truncation for each scheme?
>
> c) What is the stability condition for each of these schemes?
>
> d) In what range of $\chi$ the scheme is unconditionally unstable?
>
> e) Classify the schemes in (a) as (i) dissipative, and (ii) dispersive.

### ATTEMPT

(a) Notice that if $\chi = 0$, then we obtain the central explicit scheme. If we write the numerical discretization as

$$u_j^{n+1} = u_j^n - \frac{ a \Delta t }{2 \Delta x} (u_{j+1}^n - u_{j-1}^n) + \frac{ \chi \Delta t }{\Delta x^2} (u_{j+1}^n - 2 u_j^n + u_{j-1}^n )$$

And one can see that if $\chi = a \Delta t/2$, then we have the LW scheme. If $\chi = a \Delta x/2$, then we have

$$ u_j^{n+1} = u_j^n + \frac{ a \Delta t }{\Delta x} (u_{j+1}^n - u_j^n) $$

which is forward explicit and if $\chi = - a \Delta x/2$, we obtain backward explicit. Now if $\chi = \frac{ \Delta x^2}{2 \Delta t }$, then we obtain Lax-Friedrichs.

We go to part (c) as (b) is trivial. Perhaps  we can combine (c) and (d) in a single problem if we apply the discrete fourier transform:

$$ \hat{u}^{n+1} = \hat{u}^n - r( e^{ij \xi} -e^{-ij \xi } ) \hat{u}^n + \frac{ 2 \chi r }{a \Delta x} (e^{ij \xi} -e^{-ij \xi } -2 ) \hat{u}^n$$

Now, am I on the right track here? Is this the correct approach? As for e), I need some suggestions, how would we approach it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The proposed values of $\chi$ in a) are correct. One notes that the method is a straightforward finite-difference approximation of the advection-diffusion method $u_t + au_x = \chi u_{xx}$. Introducing the Courant number $r = |a| {\Delta t}/{\Delta x}$, the diffusion constants from a) rewrite as
$$
\chi \in |a|\frac{\Delta x}{2} \times \left\lbrace \frac{1}{r},\,
1,\,
r,\,
0 \right\rbrace ,
$$
which correspond to the numerical viscosities of the Lax-Friedrichs, upwind, Lax-Wendroff, and central explicit method, respectively. One notes that if $0<r<1$, then those values of $\chi$ are sorted in decreasing order.

As done in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2743887/418542), let us assume a perturbation of the form $u_j^n = \xi^n e^{-\text i k j \Delta x}$, where $\xi = \text e^{\text i \omega \Delta t}$. Note that $\omega$ is a complex number, with real part $\omega_R$ and imaginary part $\omega_I$. Injecting this Ansatz in the time-stepping formula, Euler's formulas lead to
$$
\xi = 1 + \text i r \sin( k \Delta x) + 2\lambda \left( \cos(k \Delta x) -1 \right) ,
$$
where $r$ is the Courant number and
$$
\lambda = {\chi}\frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x^2} \in \left\lbrace \frac{1}{2},\,
\frac{r}{2},\,
\frac{r^2}{2},\,
0 \right\rbrace
$$
denotes the Fourier number. From this equation, one equates the real and imaginary parts:
\begin{aligned}
\text{Re}\, \xi &= e^{-\omega_I \Delta t}\cos(\omega_R \Delta t) = 1 + 2\lambda \left( \cos(k \Delta x) -1 \right) ,\\
\text{Im}\, \xi &= e^{-\omega_I \Delta t}\sin(\omega_R \Delta t) = r \sin( k \Delta x)  \, .
\end{aligned}
The stability can be analyzed in terms of the squared amplification factor $|\xi|^2$ which has to be smaller than one. Hence, we must have
$$
|\xi|^2 - 1 = 4\lambda^2 - 4 \lambda + r^2 + 4 \lambda (1-2\lambda) Z + (4\lambda^2 - r^2) Z^2 \leq 0
$$
for all $Z = \cos( k \Delta x)$ in $[-1, 1]$.
The dispersion is analyzed in terms of the phase velocity ${\omega_R}/{k}$ with
${\omega_R}\Delta t = \arctan\left[{\text{Im}\, \xi}/{\text{Re}\, \xi}\right]$.
The attenuation is analyzed in terms of
${\omega_I}\Delta t = -\ln |\xi|$
which is non-negative if $|\xi| \leq 1$ (cf. e.g. (1) p. 182).

(1) E. Godlewski, P.-A. Raviart, Numerical Approximation of Hyperbolic Systems of Conservation Laws, Springer, 1996. doi:10.1007/978-1-4612-0713-9

Comment: You are using the fourier modes to analyze stability, correct? Was there any particular reason to use this? We could use the discrete fourier transform as well.

Comment: @James I guess that DFT would work as well.

Comment: If you dont mind asking, can you explain a little bit more how to analyze the dispersion/dissipation?