# Inequality: $|1+4(x^4-x^2)|\leq 1$ implies $|x|\leq1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

My question comes from here: [Lax-Wendroff method for linear advection - Stability analysis](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2743887/lax-wendroff-method-for-linear-advection-stability-analysis), but nobody needs to know anything about Lax-Wendroff. My question is very easy.

Basically, in the last line of the answer, it is claimed that

$$|1+4(x^4-x^2)|\leq 1$$
is satisfied if $|x|\leq1$.

And I drew a plot to confirm this:
[image]

My question is, how do I obtain the desired inequality $|x|\leq1$ algebraically?

Comment: The question in the title is the converse of the question in the body of the question. Do you want to show that that inequality implies $|x|\le1$ or the other way around???

Comment: I guess a sufficient condition is what we want for stability, but I wanted to know if we could get the final inequality to be as big as possible, so I wanted what I asked (if you get what I mean)

Comment: If I got what you meant I wouldn't be asking. There are two different questions above - which one is the one you meant to ask?????

Comment: Sorry for not being clear; I wanted to show that the inequality implies $|x|\leq 1$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Note $|(2x^2-1)^2|\le1$ iff $-1\le2x^2-1\le1$, i.e. $0\le x^2\le1$.

Answer (score 3):

Assume that $|x| > 1$, now we have $x^4 > x^2$, so $|1+\text{something positive}| > 1$ always. Hence, the opposite.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it as follows:\begin{align}\bigl|1+4(x^4-x^2)\bigr|\leqslant1&\iff\bigl(1+4(x^4-x^2)\bigr)^2\leqslant1\\&\iff8(x^4-x^2)+16(x^4-x^2)^2\leqslant0\\&\iff(x^4-x^2)\bigl(1+2(x^2-x^2)\bigr)\leqslant0\\&\iff(x^4-x^2)\bigl(x^4+(x^2-1)^2\bigr)\leqslant0\\&\iff x^2(x^2-1)\leqslant0\\&\iff x^2\leqslant1\\&\iff x\in[-1,1].\end{align}